# URL POST not hitting isset($_POST)

Tags: php

I have a simple php test page as follows

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hitme']))
{
    echo "hello world";
}
?>
```

I'm hitting this page as, `http://www.abc.com/page.php?hitme=true` but this is not echo'ing anything. Is something wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$_GET['hitme']`, not `$_POST`, since you passed the value in the query string.  `$_POST` would hold values sent via a `<form action='post'>`, but not values passed in the query string.

```
if(isset($_GET['hitme'])) {...}
```

It's recommended to read [about the differences between PHP's superglobal arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` only contains variables which are *posted* to the page as part of an HTTP POST request. If you are typing the address into your browsers address bar, you're issuing a GET request, not a POST request, and no variables will be set in `$_POST`. Even if you are issuing a POST request, variables specified on the query string will *still* only be available inside `$_GET`, so for this example your using the wrong array either way.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` when it's in the URL

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the URL, e.g. `http://example.com/index.php?hitme=true`, it's in `$_GET`.

However, if you want it to be in `$_POST`, you'd have to do something like this (very basic example):

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hitme" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post data!" />
</form>
```

This script will allow the user to check it if wanted, and then click "Post data!".

However, it won't be in `$_POST` as long the user didn't click the button.
As for `$_GET`, it will be there as long as it's in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [`$_REQUEST['hitme']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), this one will check both `$_POST['hitme']` and `$_GET['hitme']`